# Width of a <NavDropdown> in react-bootstrap 5

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

New day, new problem. I'm not good at CSS, yikes.

I want to set the width of the dropdown in react-bootstrap, I tried with:

```js
<NavDropdown style={{width: "5vw"}} title="Utente" id="navbarScrollingDropdown">
{/* ... */}
</NavDropdown>
```

Thinking this would've worked, all it did is mess up the title. Any way to change the width of the dropdown without messing up his title?

`Nodejs ver: 16.9.1` `npm ver: 7.24` `bootstrap ver: 5.1.1` `react-bootstrap ver: 2.0.0-rc.0` `react ver: 17.0.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it on one of the Dropdown items...

```
       <NavDropdown title="Utente" id="navbarScrollingDropdown">
           <NavDropdown.Item style={{width:'5vw'}} href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
           <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
           <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
       </NavDropdown>
```

https://codeply.com/p/Mgv3aww20F

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
.dropdown-menu {
        min-width: auto !important;
    }
    
    #navbarScrollingDropdown {
        width: fit-content;
    }
```